# How to automatically change the parameters in the constructor function in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: class, intellij-idea, parameters, constructor, field

Say that I add one more field `private String model` to my `Dimensions` class. Then I also have to add the parameter `String model` to my constructor and then set `this.model=model`. Is there any way to get Intellij do that for me automatically whenever I add a new field to my class?

```java
public class Dimensions {

    private int length;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Dimensions(int length, int width, int height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the caret on the member and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This will open a contex menu, from it choose "Add constructor parameter" and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: What if I do the reverse? I mean if I delete `private int length`, how would I reflect that change in my constructor?